# Fill Docker Container from existing remote database

Tags: mysql, synchronization, docker

I do have *n* nodes managed by Kubernetes, all of them running several containers. A container may contain a database alongside with an application. As containers should be stateless, all data within the container's database would be lost (uppon restart or redeployment via Kubernetes). Hence, I thought of a central database (See Fig. 2.6.2 Management) which contains all Databases for permanent persistence. The idea is to link the Container's Database via *Master-Master* synchronization to the related permanent persisted database.

As each Node runs docker and boots up the image into a container, how does the container's database initially synchronize all the master's content? It can't be pre-shipped within the image, as the image will be build by an external source, only providing the compiled services and not knowing anything about the actual database(s) structure/source.

The only thing I can currently think of is a sqldump that gets requested by the container on boot-up. (via SMB, SSH,...) But that seems a bit off to me.

[image]

Comment: do you share the data over all instances? does each instance need its own database _server_?

Comment: Yes, they need to share data across all instances. The idea of the Master-Master config is, that each container has full read-write access. Furthermore, it continues to operate even if other nodes/management node goes down. Due to the DB structure it is possible that 'n' nodes and their containers operate on the same table, not interfering with each other. My assumption: if 'n' nodes with 'n' containers would rely on a single db instance, they aren't failsave.

Comment: hmmm its really tricky/impossible to sync a relational db master-master-master. think about transactions. If you have immutable or sharded data you could maybe do it, but its going to use a lot of bandwidth and disc space for all that duplication. Why not just have a separate base metal database and failover cluster?

Comment: I decided to go with a cluster, consisting of two databases in master-master config. Guess that strips out a lot of complexity.